# Do Indian citizens need a visa for Okinawa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, japan, okinawa

I m holding a Indian passport. And I m going to jeju(south korea). My flight is from Mumbai to jeju. Jeju to Okinawa. Okinawa to mumbai. Do I need visa for Okinawa. Jeju visa is on arrival. I don't have a visa of Okinawa. Do I need or not.

Comment: Do you intend to stay in Okinawa?  Or are you just transiting on your way to somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you need a visa.  Okinawa is a part of Japan, and [Indian citizens require visas to enter Japan](http://www.in.emb-japan.go.jp/short_term%20visas.html).

Comment: If it is an international transfer only, then a visa will not be required as entry to Japan will not take place.

Comment: I would be very surprised if the OP is just transiting Okinawa on their way to India (for one thing, there are no direct flights), but checking.

Comment: I thought so too. In fact I couldn't find any India bound flights leaving Okinawa. However, unless there is more information, that is what OP is asking...